# How to programmatically set chart series title in ModernUI WPF chart

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts, modern-ui

I need to set the chart series title programatically using the ModernUI WPF charting.

**I create the charts in the following way, allowing for easy data entry:**

```
public class MainViewModel
{    
    public ObservableCollection<ChartData> Populations {get; set;}    
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Populations = new ObservableCollection<ChartData>();         
    }

    public void Add(string key, int value)
    {
        Populations.Add(new ChartData() { dataName = key, dataValue = value });
    }
}

public class ChartData
{
    public string dataName { get; set; }
    public int dataValue  { get; set; }
}
```

**And then in the Main Window:**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainViewModel mvm = new MainViewModel();
    mvm.Add("asd", 123);
    mvm.Add("sdfs", 133);
    mvm.Add("asda", 129);
    mvm.Add("asgfgfhd", 23);

    test1.DataContext = mvm;
}
```

**In the XAML:**

```
    <chart:StackedColumnChart x:Name="test1" ChartSubTitle="Population in millions"
        ChartTitle="Countries by population" Margin="10,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1573" Height="475" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <chart:StackedColumnChart.Series>

            <chart:ChartSeries DisplayMember="dataName"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Populations}"
                *SeriesTitle="World largest populations"*
                ValueMember="dataValue" />
        </chart:StackedColumnChart.Series>      

    </chart:StackedColumnChart>
```

How do I set programmatically the **SeriesTitle** value?

Comment: You can try to set `x:Name` attributes to the series and access it from code. Or use `test1.Series.First().SeriesTitle`

Comment: test1.Series.First().SeriesTitle works perfectly, thank you. If you write it as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it. Now I'm wondering how to add Series programmatically... can you help with that, or should I open a new topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to change the title programmatically, you can access properties of the chart control and set some other values:

```
var chartSeries = test1.Series.First();
chartSeries.SeriesTitle = "New title";
```

Also you can create and add series in C# code:

```
var series = new ChartSeries();
series.ItemsSource = items; // a collection from somewhere else
series.DisplayMember = "dataName";
series.ValueMember = "dataValue";
series.SeriesTitle = "Title";

test1.Series.Add(series);
```

Comment: this is perfect, you are my hero :) I wonder if everybody else figured this out on their own, or maybe this'll help others too. THANKS A LOT!!!

Comment: last question, if you dont mind. If I use LINQ to limit the items to a criteria, I cannot seem to assign it to the DataContext. I can see that it finds items, but the chart is empty. Do you know why?             var modMvm = mvm.Populations.Where(x => x.dataName == "asd");
   
            test1.DataContext = modMvm;

Comment: @Marton You should check you binding expressions in the XAML markup. If the DataContex is a collection, the binding should be `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`